# Turning data frame observations into list of lists

Tags: json, r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R with three columns.

1. lhs
2. rhs
3. conviction

> ```
> example <- data.frame(lhs=c('phones', 'phones', 'phones',
>                             'shoes', 'shoes', 'shoes'),
>                       rhs=c('chargers', 'headphones', 'shoes',
>                             'shirts', 'pants', 'socks'),
>                       conviction=c(1.376, 1.259, 1.087,
>                                    1.295, 1.083, 0.978))
> ```

Here's a look at the output.

[image: output]

What I want to be able to do is turn this into a data frame with one column per item in lhs and a list of lists as the second column with the format [[rhs, conviction],[rhs,conviction]]

Something like this:

[image]

The end goal of all of this is to have a nested JSON file.

Final JSON should resemble this:

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Would `library(tidyr); example %>% nest(-lhs)` be sufficient? Maybe more usefully, what should the resulting JSON look like?

Comment: Thanks alistaire. I made an edit to include ideal JSON. Playing with the suggestion now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tidyverse` to `nest` part of the data frame. This will still leave you with a nested tibble column. To convert this column to a list, you can use `map` and `lapply` like so

```
library(tidyverse)
ans <- example %>%
          nest(-lhs) %>%
          mutate(data = map(data, ~lapply(1:nrow(.x), function(i) .x[i,]))) %>%
          rename(rhs = data)
```

Here's what the `rhs` column looks like

```
ans$rhs
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# # A tibble: 1 x 2
       # rhs conviction
    # <fctr>      <dbl>
# 1 chargers      1.376

# [[1]][[2]]
# # A tibble: 1 x 2
         # rhs conviction
      # <fctr>      <dbl>
# 1 headphones      1.259

# [[1]][[3]]
# # A tibble: 1 x 2
     # rhs conviction
  # <fctr>      <dbl>
# 1  shoes      1.087


# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# # A tibble: 1 x 2
     # rhs conviction
  # <fctr>      <dbl>
# 1 shirts      1.295

# [[2]][[2]]
# # A tibble: 1 x 2
     # rhs conviction
  # <fctr>      <dbl>
# 1  pants      1.083

# [[2]][[3]]
# # A tibble: 1 x 2
     # rhs conviction
  # <fctr>      <dbl>
# 1  socks      0.978
```

*EDIT* to return specific format of output

I realized you still get a list of tibbles with the above answer, to convert to a list of vectors, use the following (`unlist` added)

```
mutate(data = map(data, ~lapply(1:nrow(.x), function(i) unlist(.x[i,]))))
```

Comment: `purrr::map` and `lapply` do the same thing, so using both is confusing. Also, in R there's always a more direct route than iterating over indices.

Comment: @alistaire I'm always confused about how to deal with the scoping of nested map statements. For instance, `map(data, ~map(1:nrow(.x), ~function(i) unlist(.x[.x?,])))`. How do I refer to both the outer-map `.x` and the inner-map `.x`? This is the only reason I used an inner-lapply. Thanks for any insight

Comment: @alistaire Since I am trying to iterate through a data.frame/tibble, is there a better way to iterate through the data? (I like `iterators::iter` but it can't be used with `map`). Thanks for any thoughts

Comment: If you use `split`, you don't need to iterate over rows: `example %>% nest(-lhs, .key = 'rhs') %>% mutate(rhs = map(rhs, ~split(.x, seq(nrow(.x)))))`. More generally, if you're iterating over iterations, you should first consider if it's necessary (Is it vectorizable?). If so, consider `modify_depth`. Syntax-wise, you can do `map(map, ~.x)` or just use regular function notation in purrr to differentiate variables instead of the `~` style.

Comment: @alistaire, thanks. 1: `split` is a better option. 2: Didn't realize I could use regular function notation. thanks for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

To get the requisite JSON structure, you really need a list, as a data.frame can't give you the nested structure you need. Using a bit of dplyr, you can `summarise` each set of grouped data into a data.frame, using the `rhs` as names for each value of `conviction`. Setting the names of the resulting list to the values of `rhs` and converting to JSON, you get

```r
library(dplyr)

example <- data.frame(lhs=c('phones', 'phones', 'phones', 'shoes', 'shoes', 'shoes'),
                      rhs=c('chargers', 'headphones', 'shoes', 'shirts', 'pants', 'socks'),
                      conviction=c(1.376, 1.259, 1.087, 1.295, 1.083, 0.978))

example %>% 
    group_by(lhs) %>% 
    summarise(rest = list(as.data.frame(t(setNames(conviction, rhs))))) %>% 
    { setNames(.$rest, .$lhs) } %>% 
    jsonlite::toJSON(pretty = TRUE)
#> {
#>   "phones": [
#>     {
#>       "chargers": 1.376,
#>       "headphones": 1.259,
#>       "shoes": 1.087
#>     }
#>   ],
#>   "shoes": [
#>     {
#>       "shirts": 1.295,
#>       "pants": 1.083,
#>       "socks": 0.978
#>     }
#>   ]
#> }
```